# Why is the Qt Creator Ubuntu Publish Screen Empty?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qml, qt-creator

I'm trying to publish an app to the Ubuntu Store, however something is wrong with Qt Creator (or something else).

I used to be able to see this:

[image: Qt Creator - Ubuntu Publish Screen for Apps]

But now all I see is this:

[image: Qt Creator - An Empty Ubuntu Publish Screen for Apps]

As you can see (or read, if you're using a Reader with no images), the second image here isn't displaying things like the General tab which allows me to enter details such as Maintainer, Name, Description, Security Policy Groups - it doesn't have a Manifest tab AppArmor tab or Excludes tab either. The Create Package button is gone.

All I am left with is a blank screen with only 1 enabled button which reads 'Validate existing Click package', but when I click that (since there's nothing else I can do, it seems...), it takes me to my Projects directory where all my apps are listed. I select the app in question, and I can't click the open button on the dialog because there is no *.click file anywhere to be seen.

Have I done something wrong? Do you know what's going on here?

Also, I read that in order to publish to the store, we need to create "Click apps". I've searched the universe for this phrase and have come up empty handed. How do I create a "Click app"? I thought the app I was creating was a click app (I went to Qt Creator > Qt Quick Application > ...).

Links:

Tutorial for Publishing apps: http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/packaging-click-apps/

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I'm thinking you have to create the Click package *first*..

Comment: Oh. @Seth, how would i do that? I searched for that but it just takes me back to the same tutorial that I'm having issues with now

Comment: @jay_t55: have you checked [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1215937)? Also, could you please link the tutorials that you have tried? [This](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/packaging-click-apps/) is the one? Whoever downvoted can explain why? I gave an upvote myself. Also, which device are you trying to build for?

Comment: @jay_t55: do you have the manifest.json in your project directory or somewhere, e.g which is coming from the template?

Comment: @lpapp Thank you for the links. Im checking them out now and will get back. I am not sure about the downvote, wasnt me. Ill go on the pc and link the tutorials.

Comment: @lpapp It's not generating manifests anymore. I just looked and it's not there.

Comment: lpapp regarding your first link, everyone keeps talking about the Packaging tab/button on the left - but in Qt Creator (the version I have - latest), there is no Packaging tab/button anywhere; only a Publish button/tab. Also, re the first link, not sure if it's related, but I am new to Ubuntu stuff so maybe I just don't understand yet. I'm still reading through it all. RE: Your second link, yep that's the one. I have updated my question to include the link also.

Comment: @jay_t55: OK, there is one major flaw in your worlflow, namely: do not select new project > qtquick application, but new project > ubuntu > something. You need `apt-get install ubuntu-sdk`, not the official Qt SDK if you had not done so. It will also install the `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu` package with its own toolchain.

Comment: @lpapp but if I go > Ubuntu > ... it only lets me create HTML5 apps and not QML/C++ ones :( Unless there's a way I haven't seen.

Comment: @lpapp I think I did install the Ubuntu SDK. I'll check again to make sure. Pretty sure I did. Ah, good. I did install it at some point. Terminal says: "ubuntu-sdk is already the newest version." Hmmm, it also says "qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu is the already the newest version." I'm going to go and try your steps. See what happens.

Comment: Please reinstall the ubuntu SDK if it is installed, just in case. Does it work afterwards? See if that still does not work, you need to setup qmake manually. Go to the settings page. Does it work afterwards? By the way, you obviously have not downvoted your own question since it is not possible. :p

Comment: I'm going to try and reinstall Ubuntu SDK adn see if that works. I just went to New Proj. > Ubuntu > HTML5 and even though there is a manifest.json file showing up the Publish screen is still empty :/ Even the Ubuntu > QML (but no other language) one which has a manifest.json file won't display the Publish screen

Comment: @jay_t55: that is really strange. Can you show the manifest file content? I am getting the impression that you use the wrong QtCreator. Try to open up the one from the ubuntu sdk. Just type `ubuntu-sdk` in the console. Or is that the version that you were already using?

Comment: @lpapp Sure, one moment. And lol. I thought you meant somebody downvoted one of your comments or something.

Comment: @lpapp Here's a paste of the manifest.json file: http://pastebin.com/Z5Q0A4aW

Comment: See my previous comment. Also, is it 14.04 as in your question, or 14.10 as in your manifest?

Comment: :-O I'ma hug you! It works perfectly when I go: ubuntu-sdk in Terminal! AAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you! :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you are using QtCreator from Qt Project proper instead of using the Ubuntu SDK, which delivers its own custom version of QtCreator.

In order to get things done for this, you will need to use the Ubuntu SDK. [First you need to install it](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

This will also install the `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu` package, its own toolchain, etc. Then you can run it e.g. from the command line as follows:

```
$ ubuntu-sdk
```

You can also search in the Unity Dash Applications lens for “Ubuntu SDK” as the image shows below:

[image]

You can also just start typing the name in the search line as the images shows below:

[image]

Please make sure that you go to the following:

```
New Project > Ubuntu > Simple UI/Html/QML/etc
```

[image]

rather than e.g. what you tried based on your question:

```
New Project > Qt Quick Application
```

You may also with [to set up the click targets and device kits](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/sdk/tutorials/click-targets-and-device-kits/) part of which (Build and Run) is presented below inline:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @lpapp. I really appreciate it. You can have ALL my reps now lol

Comment: Sorry, it's telling me I can't award the bounty for another 16 hours. I'll come back then to award it.

Comment: @jay_t55: LOL, glad that it helped. I think they could update the official documentation to make it a bit more clear as I expect newcomers struggling with this. No worries about the bounty.

Comment: Any idea how I could still create QML/HTML with C++ apps by going to New Proj. > Ubuntu > ...?

Comment: @jay_t55: have you tried to setup qmake manually as indicated above or is that already set up?

Comment: Oh sorry i will do that now. I must have overlooked that.

Comment: @jay_t55: np, there were far too many comments, so it is easy to overlook something. ;-) So, go to Settings > Build and Run and set up the things in there.

Comment: @jay_t55: as for the bounty, I would hold it off for a week to see if there is any better answer coming up than mine. The bounty will be automatically awarded in your case if there is a selected answer, even if you forget about it.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother again, but when you said to setup QMake so I could create qml with c++ apps, how exactly should I set it up? I did go to Tools > Build & Run > ... and looking at the different options, they don't make much sense to me, and I haven't been able to find anything online yet either. I'm actually wondering how anybody gets things done on Linux sometimes. Maybe it's just cause I'm really new to Linux in general.

Comment: @jay_t55: cannot you just automatically add C++ files in QML projects? [This](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/sdk/tutorials/click-targets-and-device-kits/) shows how to set the device kit up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) well , luckily i have been developing ubuntu HTML5 apps recently , so i have been in your place before , you will be able to integrate your c++ code using the QML option ( as ubuntu developers have only 2 options either HTML5 or QML ).

Here is a sample project found on xda to create a simple calculator app ( pay attention how to include your cpp file ):

**File Name:apcalc-qml.pro**

```
QT += qml quick
# If your application uses the Qt Mobility libraries, uncomment the following
# lines and add the respective components to the MOBILITY variable.
# CONFIG += mobility
# MOBILITY +=

#C++ source files
SOURCES +=  cpp/main.cpp\
            cpp/applicationdata.cpp\

#C++ header files
HEADERS  += cpp/applicationdata.h

#Path to the libraries...
INCLUDEPATH +=  $$PWD\
                $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib

#Path to "other files" in this case  the QML-Files
OTHER_FILES += \
    qml/main.qml\
    qml/basicCalc/*.qml
```

**File Name:main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QtQml/qqmlcontext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include  "applicationdata.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    ApplicationData data;

    //Resize Mode so the content of the QML file will scale to the window size
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    //With this we can add the c++ Object to the QML file
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationData", &data);

    //Resolve the relativ path to the absolute path (at runtime)
    const QString qmlFilePath= QString::fromLatin1("%1/%2").arg(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(), "qml/main.qml");
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(qmlFilePath));

    //For debugging we print out the location of the qml file
    QByteArray ba = qmlFilePath.toLocal8Bit();
    const char *str = ba.data();
    printf("Qml File:%s\n",str);

    //Not sure if this is nessesary, but on mobile devices the app should start in fullscreen mode
    #if defined(Q_WS_SIMULATOR) || defined(Q_OS_QNX)
    view.showFullScreen();
    #else
    view.show();
    #endif
    return app.exec();
}
```

**File Name:main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import "basicCalc"
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
MainView {
    //objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"
    applicationName: "apcalc-qml"
    automaticOrientation:true;
    width: units.gu(60);
    height: units.gu(100);
    id:root
    Tabs {
        objectName: "Tabs"
        ItemStyle.class: "new-tabs"
        anchors.fill: parent
        id:mainWindow;
        Tab {
            objectName: "Calculator"
            title: "Calculator"
            page:BasicCalc{
                width: root.width;
                height: root.height-root.header.height;
                anchors.top: parent.top;
                anchors.topMargin: root.header.height;
                onToCalculateChanged: {
                    //access to the c++ Object 
                    result=applicationData.calculate(toCalculate);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**File Name:applicationdata.h**

```
#ifndef APPLICATIONDATA_H
#define APPLICATIONDATA_H
#include <QObject>

class ApplicationData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ApplicationData(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString calculate(QString) const;
signals:

public slots:
};
#endif // APPLICATIONDATA_H
```

**File Name:applicationdata.cpp**

```
#include "applicationdata.h"
ApplicationData::ApplicationData(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}
QString ApplicationData::calculate(QString command) const {
    // Some Logic comes here
    return command;
}
```

You can check the full tutorial [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2265480) , though this app is intended to work for ubuntu touch  but i believe that all QML projects follow the same procedure.

**Publishing App :**

First of all **click App** means a package , a one file click > installs your app AKA (Personal Package Archives (PPA) ) , in order to publish your app , you need to follow some procedure metioned in details [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/get-started/) , eventhough the xda tutorial explains everything in a clear way.